# Getting a file not found error when I try to check in file using web services?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-services

I am using the following code to create a file and then check it in:

```
//Some other code above.  The following line works fine.
createdItem = ceoList.UpdateListItems("Pages", newItem);
//But this line throws a file not found error
ceoList.CheckInFile("http://myServer:88/" + newUrl, "Automated version created by the Publish Friday Memo on the internal sharepoint site.", "2");
```

If I debug this and place the line: `"http://myServer:88/" + newUrl` in my immediate window I get the url I would expect.  If I navigate to that URL i see the page I want.  But when I run the `CheckInFile` line I get a SOAP file not found exception.  Any idea why this would happen?

Below is the stack trace:

> SOAP exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot
>   find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetMetadataForUrl(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32&
>   plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32&
>   plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetListItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFields,
>   String[] fields)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataImpl.CheckInFile(String
>   pageUrl, String comment, String CheckinType)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataValidatorImpl.CheckInFile(String
>   pageUrl, String comment, String CheckinType)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Lists.CheckInFile(String pageUrl,
>   String comment, String CheckinType)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting around this by adding the following line after I declared the `ceoList` instance:

```
ceoList.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
```

Apparently the connection is closed after a call to a web service unless you add this line.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing.aspx

I think you can also reauthenticate before every call instead of adding this line.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

When using a client such as a ListsSoapClient, you can check the State property and reopen the connection like this:

```
if (listsClient.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
    listsClient.Open();
```